# htaccess file with ubuntu and WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ubuntu

I set the following "htaccess" file code on WordPress folder

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPresssss
```

but when typing some URL the 404 pages are not showing properly and I don't get the custom 404 error page. example
https://healthguruwealth.com/fgdfdgf

Comment: First go to admin dashboard once save the permalinks

Comment: Is the `.htaccess` file exactly as written in your question? (I corrected the formatting, but there is no opening `<IfModule>` directive to match the closing `</IfModule>`? This would result in an error - if it is doing anything at all.) The response from your site URL is from an Nginx server, not Apache? (`.htaccess` is Apache only.) A URL like `/?feed` _does_ work, which suggests pretty permalinks are not enabled and your `.htaccess` file is doing nothing?

Answer (score 0):

By default, WordPress doesn't create custom 404 pages. You can create a new 404 templates. Please follow the instruction as per the link below:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Error_404_Page

Or, you can create through plugins like [ithemes security](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/)

Comment: the problem is that also urls that need to work like https://healthguruwealth.com/feed return error 404 when they should not

Comment: The .htaccess code that you have mentioned is generated by default. If you are changing the URL structure or any changes related to the slug, you need to reset the permalink from the backed. I have fixed a similar issue through the ithemes security plugin.